# How can we give option to enter a text input in Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter and to be able to read a file param in its groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to use active choice reactive reactive reference parameters in Jenkins Freestyle Job where I want to read a file and show some of its content as value of this reactive reference parameter, and also to be able to edit the input.

Can this be achieved?

The configuration looks like this as of now :

[image]

The output I am expecting is something like this:

[image]

This is the input textbox where "ABS= DEF= " is output from fileconfig param, and also this input is not hidden and can be edited if need be, and then should be passed to Jenkins build as parameter.

Note: I used  : return "<input name="value" type="text">" in groovy script which is also not working for me.

Comment: Also tried using this but to no avail :

return "<input name=\"value\" value=\"${ReactiveRefParam}\" class=\"setting-input\" type=\"text\">"